# syncronize git remote repositories with iis application

Tags: git

we are one team of php proggrammer and now we decided to choose git as source control for our future workflow. 
basically our current workflow is work and test locally and then upload it to production app (windows server,Iis).

What we have now is :
 1. client NoteBooks. (our local working directory)
 2. windows server ( where iis web app and remote repository reside).

we have setting our server machine with scm-manager for collaborate progress. how do we syncing the files from our remote repository to our production app folder in iis ?

so if we doing our git push to remote repo its naturally applicable to our iis web application.

Thanks before guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workflow will also depend on how many developers will add new features concurrently. Anyway, I'd proceed as follows.

- Local machines:

  - One single working repository with the following branches:

    - Branch *master* (features tested and ready for production)
    - One or more *"unstable"* branches for in-progress development
- Remote Windows server:

  - One single **bare** repository with one single *master* branch

Then,

- Work on your *"unstable"* branches locally.
- Whenever a feature is ready and tested:

  - Pull from the local *master* branch the Windows *master* branch (to merge and resolve locally conflicts with changes made by others in the meantime)
  - Pull from the local *master* branch the *"unstable"* branch containing the new feature
  - Push the local *master* branch to the Windows *master* branch to update the public production code

Of course, the last step can be made automatic by a proper [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) which pushes the changes whenever the local *master* branch is updated.

Comment: thanks for the tips. but im looking to syncronize the remote repositories with app folder in iis (currently remote repo and app folder in the same machine but in different folder).